# Debian live : halt on usb eject?

Tags: debian, live-usb, tails-os

The TAILS distribution contains this functionality: if you brutally remove the USB key from the machine, the system halts.

Is it easy to add this functionality to a live-build procedure under Debian?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to do that, you might [ask the Tails's teem.](https://tails.boum.org/support/index.en.html)